# I installed supertuxcart and can't figure out how to launch it

Tags: 11.04, unity

I installed supertuxcart and can't figure out how to launch it or how to get Unity to point to it.
(My system is AMD 939 4400x2, overclocked@2600mhz, DFI LANParty UT expert motherboard, 2x1Gig khx 400-xfx 7600 512mbx2 SLI, sata1 320Gig root sata1 400Gig, both Seagates.)

Answer (score 3):

Pressing `Alt-F2` and starting to type "supertux..." should show it in the search results.

Alternatively, you can right-click on the Applications button (a magnifying glass icon, third from the bottom), select Games category and click on Show all results.

Comment: @tim o: Please mark the answer correct by clicking on the tick mark to the left.

Answer (score 3):

Press super (winkey) and start to type supertux until it's the only icon left and press enter, or just click on it when you find it. The dash learns from that, so if you often run supertux, then it'll be very quick to run. I often play PokerTH, for instance, so I can just press super and type "po" and press enter. Actually, it seems I can just type "p" now :)

You can also drag the icon to your launcher, right click and "Keep on launcher" if you're going to use it very often.

I love Unity :)